# Weird Deletion null error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to delete from a join table I made and I'm getting a weird error I cant figure out.

Here are my models

```
class ArticlesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
 # attr_accessible :title, :body
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :article
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :title
 belongs_to :user

 has_many :articles_users
 has_many :likes, :through => :articles_users, :class_name => 'User', :source => :user    
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
 has_many :articles, :order => 'id DESC'
 has_and_belongs_to_many :badges

 has_many :articles_users
 has_many :likes, :through => :articles_users, :class_name => 'Article', :source => :article
end
```

Testing in the Rails Console you can see the error:

```
> a = Article.find(13) 
> a.articles_users #works fine, returns an array of users who "like" the article
> a.articles_users.where(user_id: 3) #works as well
> a.articles_users.where(user_id: 3).first.destroy #this is where the error is thrown!
```

Here is there error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'articles_users.' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `articles_users` WHERE `articles_users`.`` = NULL
```

Why does it seem to be completely ignoring the where hash? Please help me with this I've spent hours today trying to figure it out.

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The `articles_users` table has 2 columns: `article_id` and `user_id`

**Edit:**

This is copy and pasted from the console:

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > a.articles_users.where(user_id: 3).first
ArticlesUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `articles_users`.* FROM `articles_users` WHERE    `articles_users`.`article_id` = 13 AND `articles_users`.`user_id` = 3 LIMIT 1
=> #<ArticlesUser user_id: 3, article_id: 13>
```

Comment: what is output of a.articles_users.where(user_id: 3).first

Comment: @priteshJ Just updated the question with the answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried and reproduced your issue.

From Your output it seems you don't have a id column in ArticlesUser
which is the cause if issue.

```
=> #<ArticlesUser user_id: 3, article_id: 13>
```

I tried adding id column to the table and it worked like charm.
Created a new migration and add it

```
 add_column :articles_users, :id, :primary_key
```

When you destroy a record rails uses its id as a reference to delete it from database.

Check example.

```
 DELETE FROM `articles_users` WHERE `articles_users`.`id` = 1
```

Comment: I thought it was bad practice to have an ID column on a join table?

Comment: seems like rails uses it internally in some way

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution without primary key, if you're interested.

**EDIT** : It's pretty close to this : [Deleting just a join table record in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831313/deleting-just-a-join-table-record-in-ruby-on-rails), but I believe that my solution is more symmetric.

First I followed a part of this : http://ngauthier.com/2010/11/restful-many-to-many-relationships-in-rails.html
I only changed in my config/routes.rb this line :

```
resources :users
```

into this :

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles, :controller => 'ArticleUsers', :only => [:index, :create, :destroy]
end
```

Then generate your ArticleUsers controller and create a method like this :

```
def delete_article
  @user.articles.delete(@article)
  redirect_to user_articles_path
end
```

Well, you'll also need filters like this one for @user :

```
def find_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]
end
```

and a similar one for @article (be careful, if you've followed the link above, you may have to put params([:id]) instead of params([:article_id]))

Then in your routes.rb add :

```
match '/users/:user_id/articles/delete_article/:id', :controller => 'ArticleUsers', :action => 'delete_article'
```

Note that if you're not using Rails 3 but Rails 4 you should replace "match" by "map.connect".

Then in your index if you write in slim, if your @items contains all the user's articles :

```
 - @items.each do |articleuser|
   tr
     td= articleuser.article.title

     td
       = link_to "article/delete_article/#{articleuser.article_id}",\
         data: { confirm: 'Confirm ?' } do
         i.icon-trash.icon.icon-large
```

That is adapted to my case where I have to display the link in a table, but you can easily adapt it to yours.

This method avoid using the destroy method that really wants an ID.

It took me some time and several sources to get to this, I hope it will help someone else !

Answer (score 0):

Foe a quick look ..I have also faced the same problem but I tried this in my code -:

```
@cart = Cart.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first
@item = @cart.cart_items.where(:product_id => params[:product_id]).first
@item.destroy
```

or in your code you can try using this like

```
@a=a.articles_users.where(user_id: 3).first
@a.destroy
```

Give it a try

Comment: @Deekor check in console whether this line is working or not a.articles_users.where(user_id: 3).first